# How do I import code to Enterprise Architect?

Tags: java, enterprise-architect

I understand that this is not directly related to programming, but I want to import the source code from a program to a project in Enterprise architect. Every online guide I found says that I need to do something through a "Code Engineering" submenu, but for some reason I don't have any options when I click it.

[image: Screenshot]

I'm using Enterprise Architect 11.0.1106 by the way.
Does anyone know how to solve this? Thanks.

Comment: On-topic for SO includes "software tools commonly used by programmers," and your question describes "a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development" so it's prefectly fine.

Answer (score 3):

`Code Engineering` is available in `Professional` edition and up.

See also [Sparx Systems: Products → Enterprise Architect → Compare Editions](http://www.sparxsystems.com/products/ea/compare-editions.html)

Answer (score 1):

@xmojmr mentions the edition, which is the most probable explanation.

It is also possible that you're using a command set which doesn't include code engineering, but I think in that case you wouldn't even see the Code Engineering menu item.